# How to set display attribute based on culture

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, culture

I am building a website with the option to change the display language, where this is determined in the URL.

For example, if we navigate to http://website.com/en-US/ the page will be in english, and http://website.com/ru-RU the website will be in Russian.

You can see the details of how I implemented this below.

My question is, is it possible for me to retrieve this data (which is saved in `PageData`) in my `ViewModel`, to set the `Display` attribute? Or should I set this value to a different variable (perhaps session?) And if so, how would I go about retrieving it?

For example, where my ViewModel currently contains:

```
[Display(Name = "Email")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

I need something like

```
[Display(Name = Resources.GetString("EmailDisplay", culture)]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Your help with this is much appreciated, thanks!

#### RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new
    {
        lang = "ru-RU",
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

#### _ViewStart.cs

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    var cultureRoute = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["lang"].ToString();
    PageData["culture"] = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureRoute);
}
```

#### _Layout.cs

```
@{ 
    var culture = @PageData["culture"];
}
```

I then have 2 Resource files (`Resources.en-US.resx` and `Resources.ru-RU.resx`), and I set the text of elemnts on the page with:

```
<h1>@Resources.ResourceManager.GetString("HomeTitle", culture)</h1>
```

Comment: Refer [this article](http://www.codedigest.com/posts/29/using-resource-file-for-dataannotations-display-attribute-with-multi-language-support-in-aspnet-mvc) for an example using resource files for localization

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks! I managed to work out a way of doing this (not sure if it is the best method, but it seems to work!) I added an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the link posted by Stephen, I was able to do this by first adding the required string in each resource file.

This means adding it to:

```
Resources.resx
Resources.en-US.resx
Resources.ru-RU.resx
```

And then defining my `ViewModel` property as:

```
[Display(Name = "LabelEmail", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Finally, I updated `_ViewStart.cs` to set the current `UICulture` (which is how the application determines which resources file to use):

```
UICulture = cultureRoute;
```